# Why doesn't jQuery click/mouseover/hover trigger same action as its mouse-triggered analog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-events, userscripts

I'm working on a browser extension that manipulates Facebook. Right now I'm focused on the "Like" button. When a user hovers over the "Like" button, Facebook's code creates a new node just below that button that contains/holds the new Facebook "reactions".

For example, open up a single post by itself from Facebook and find in the `elements` an `<a>` with the class name `UFILikeLink'`. This is the "Like" button. When a user first hovers over this, Facebook creates a new node below it with class `_2r6l`.

However, when I try to simulate that hover in order to encourage Facebook to create the new node, nothing happens. I've tried both `hover()` and `mouseenter()` on both the `UFILikeLink` node as well as its parent node with class `_khz`. Example:

```
$('.UFILikeLink').hover()
$('.UFILikeLink').mouseenter()
$('._1khz').hover()
$('._1khz').mouseenter()
```

What's going on here such that my simulated hover/mouseenter is not producing the same result as using my mouse?

Comment: try to use mouseover()

Comment: same with mouseover()